# protractor.js Expected[] to equal ["...","..."]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor

I'm trying to do the angular js tutorial, but i can't understand this error.
The code:
          var phoneNameColumn = element.all(by.repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'));

```
      function getNames() {
        return phoneNameColumn.map(function(elm, index) {
          return elm.getText();
        });
      }

      expect(getNames()).toEqual([
        "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
        "Motorola XOOM\u2122"
      ]);
```

When i run npm run protractor i see this error msg Expected[] to equal ["Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi","Motorola XOOM\u2122"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd switch from using the `.column()` to:

```
function getColumnNames() {
    return element.all(by.repeater('phone in phones')).map(function(elm, index) {
      return elm.element(by.binding('phone.name')).getText();
    });
}

expect(getColumnNames()).toEqual([
    "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
    "Motorola XOOM\u2122"
]);
```

And, I'd also [add a wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) to make the test more stable:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.binding('phone.name'))), 5000);

expect(getColumnNames()).toEqual([
    "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
    "Motorola XOOM\u2122"
]);
```

Comment: I try what you suggest but i get NoSuchElement Error: No element found using locator: by.binding('phone.name')

Comment: @JoãoHenriqueSouza okay, updated the answer - see if it helps.

Comment: @alexce, thank you very much man, the test's are working now.